# Tie pull request to work items only in the current project in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

Within Azure DevOps Server, is there a way to limit the work items that can be tied to a given pull request to only those in the current project?  Currently, when submitting a pull request Azure DevOps Server suggests and allows all work items within the project collection to be selected.

Comment: Hi Did you check out below steps, how did it go? Please let me know if there is any question

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way to limit the work items from another project to be selected in current project. You can change the **View, create, or modify work items Permissions** within an area path. Check [Restrict access to view or modify objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/restrict-access?view=azure-devops#restrict-access-to-view-or-modify-objects)

So Let's say there are Project A and B. And Restrict work items in Project B to be selected from Project A. In order to achieve this, you need to set the permissions from Project B. Please refer to below steps:

1,Go the Project setting for Project B --> Click **Project configuration** under **Boards** --> Click **Areas** -->Click the  3dots of the root Areas of Project B --> Click **Security**

[image]

2, In the **Search Box** search for **Project A team**(or any team that includes all the users in Project A, if there isnot one, you can create a team in project A to include all the users.). Then set the permission to **View work items in this node** to **Deny**.

[image]

Then any user in Project A team willnot be able to add the workitems from Project B in a pull request.

Above steps will cause some problem if a user is also in other project team. But you can override the inherited permission for this user by following step 1 to allow the the view permission for this user.

If there are many projects in your collection, you have to set repeat setting above permission for each one of them.

However you can [submit a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(click **suggest a feature** and choose **Azure devops**) that restricting view workitems permission in a  Project Level to Microsoft Development team. Hope they will consider implementing this feature.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  This does seem to work but is a bit heavy handed as we have quite a few team projects and many are working across projects.  I think for now we probably live with this and plan to submit a feature request.